# Why does it take more energy to go faster to the same place?

Tags: energy, speed

Edit: to people asking about details, I am not asking about drag. Take it to happen in vacuum, space, no drag, no other forces. I would like a general rule of thumb. This guy with e equals mv squared answered already.

This is NOT about relativistic speeds.
To go from point A to point B, in theory (maybe) I could use a certain amount of energy. If I go twice as fast, I will use energy at a double rate but only for half the time. So integrating over time the energy expenditure would seem to be identical.
Of course in the real world, it does not work like this. Cars consume far more oil per mile when they go faster.
I can understand that certain aspects of engines might not react in a linear way to what is asked of them.
However my question is more general. Is there a universal law of physics that makes it more costly to go faster to the same destination?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I go twice as fast, I will use energy at a double rate

This is not quite correct. First, in the absence of any external force, going at constant speed doesn't require any energy consumption. However, energy is needed to reach a certain speed even in the absence of external forces.

If you move with speed $v$, your (kinetic) energy is $E=\frac 12 mv^2$. However, if you move with speed $v'=2v$, your energy will be $$E'=\frac 12 mv'^2=\frac 12 m(2v)^2=2mv^2=4E.$$

These amounts of energy, $E$ and $E'$, need to be provided for reaching speeds $v$ and $v'$, respectively (assuming you start from rest). In other words, reaching twice the speed, requires four times the energy.

**Edit**: after reading the comments I've realized my answer was incomplete and made a mistake.

Comment: Alright, looks clear to me. I will wait for other answers if any, but your answer seems good enough.

Comment: So basically, if you go extremely slow, you use little energy. No wonder snails eat salad.

Comment: This is misleading.   If you ever intend to **stop** when you get to point B,  you have to dump the energy, and if you can do so in a 'regenerative' way,  then the net energy expense, in the absense of friction, wind resistance, etc etc,  is independent of speed during the trip.

Comment: To add: you've calculated the energy required to achieve a certain speed (again in the absence of any dissipative forces).  Once you reach steady-state, no energy consumption is required.

Comment: Carl you assume things that are unnecessary here. I am not asking to stop at B, just to reach it. My main concern is the energy change when speed varies, try to focus on that.

Comment: Carl, again, not the point.

Comment: Carl Witthoft has a point. The kinetic energy of an object is the energy that it possess due to its speed relative to a specific frame of reference. An object moving at constant  is not necessarily consuming energy equal to its kinetic energy unless it is overcoming dissipative forces in order to maintain its speed ( e.g., an object moving in the vacuum of space at constant velocity).

Answer (score 2):

In a semi-realistic scenario, the energy expenditure for travel consists of two parts: Accelerating to travel speed $v$, and then overcoming drag to stay at that speed. The initial acceleration is just a one-time expenditure, and can be safely ignored if we're pretending that we only accelerate once and then don't break until we arrive. So the interesting part is the energy required to overcome drag.

Drag is a force which is proportional to the square of the speed, $F_D\propto v^2$. Now the motor has to exert a force $F=-F_D$ to overcome this force. From this, we can calculate the required work:

$$W=\vert F\vert s=\vert F_D\vert s\propto v^2s,$$

where $s$ is the distance traveled. So the required work is proportional to the square of the speed.

Comment: It is hard to figure out whether the OP intended his question to be of the "assume a spherical cow with a uniform distribution of milk" situation or a real-world setup as you properly describe here.

Comment: If it happens in outer space, you get no drag and it is still a real world setup. My question is about the acceleration, assuming no friction, drag, whatever.

Comment: @Exocytosis, you gave the gas consumption of a car as your motivating example, which depends almost entirely on drag, and is not really comparable to outer space. If you do want to take a completely drag-free scenario, then the other answer is what you're looking for.

Comment: Good point. I suppose I should have refrained from talking about cars.

Comment: Ultimately it seems drag and kinetic energy both are proportional to speed squared anyway, and this is the explanation I needed.

Answer (score 0):

There are also  dissipative effects that increase with speed. For example the opposing force of air resistance on a car varies as the square of its speed all other things being equal.

Hope this helps.